# How to take screenshot in python when pc is in standby mode

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm automatically launching some python scripts that take screenshots and analysing screen content using pyautogui module.
When my pc is in standby mode, the script run but take a screenshot of the standby mode.
Are there any solution to take a screenshot of the window content even if the pc is on standby mode.

I appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such thing is possible in sleep mode, meanwhile you can prevent your computer from going into standby mode by referring to this :

- [For Linux distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61947613/14872512)
- [For windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57647169/14872512)

The main idea is using [SetThreadExecutionState function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate), for example, in your python terminal you can run :

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000002)
input('{Press enter to exit}')
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000000)
```

Comment: Thank you Younes for your response, I already force it to not go to standby mode. But the problem is that this pc is used like a server many users can use it. If one of them force it to standby mode my scripts should work. So i need an idea for that.

Comment: Preventing manual Sleep through script is such a tedious task .. assuming the server is on windows and has many users, you can maybe remove their access to Sleep/Shutdown functionnalities no ? Something like : [Win Pro/Win Enterprise tip](https://www.howtogeek.com/248742/how-to-prevent-specific-users-from-shutting-down-windows/#:~:text=In%20the%20Group%20Policy%20window,item%20and%20double%2Dclick%20it.)

Comment: Yes this is a good idea ! I will see how and if it is possible to set it up. Thanks again :)